# R returns fatal error while joining two large dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to conduct a `full_join` of `x` and `y`. `x` has 2645155 rows and 9 columns while `y` has 2645155 rows and 5 columns. Both dataframes have three similar columns

```
out <- dplyr::full_join(x, y)
```

R returns a fatal in both `rstudio` and `r`

Here is a sample [dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YN2CcNanBfHEX3WC0eMuYcEHAr_ZnRWW?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote with three columns (let say, columns `a`, `b`, and `c`) in common between two dataframes,
I recommend using this command:

```
out <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, by =c('a','b','c'))
```

Or

```
out <- dplyr::left_join(y,x, by =c('a','b','c'))
```

depending on what columns (from `x` or `y`) you prefer to be at the first in the new dataframe.
So the new dataframe (`out`) contains the three columns plus other columns merged into the new dataframe.

Comment: Still R crashes, I have edited the question and shared some data

Comment: try multicore programming in r: it will break large dataset in parts and then can bind result together